# calculating sub-total in crystal report inserting the group section in c# windows appllication

Tags: c#, windows

I am using crystal reports in c#. I have calculated the sum of all the fields in my report using the running total fields from the field explorer for a column 'TotalCost'. Now i want to calculate the subtotal in the same report according to the column 'Type' for the same column 'TotalCost'. I have two Types in my report Assets and Liabilities. How can i calculate the subtotal for the TotalCost according to the Type using the running total field. Please can anyone give me step by step advise.

Answer (score 0):

In the formula field (looks like `little x+2`) simply add the condition required for the running total to evaluate.

You'd enter it like this:  `{TableName.Type} = "Assets"`   or  `{TableName.Type} = "Liabilities"`.

If the condition isn't met then the formula tells the running total to ignore that record.